# Transition from Left Hand Drive to Right Hand Drive Car Vehicle

Tags: car, driving

I would like to know the following information.

1 By Default, a Car Automobile is manufactured as Left hand or Right hand drive. In terms of engineering efforts, how easy or difficult is the transition from Left hand to Right hand drive and vice versa?

I mean the existing Car with Left Hand drive is changed to Right Hand drive and vice versa without purchasing a new vehicle.

What will be the engineering efforts in terms of mechanical/electrical parts changes?

2 Are there countries which offer both Left hand and Right hand drive vehicles?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Minis were produced in left and right hand drive. Many others as well - Jag X type.., Subaru, Honda, BMW, most car manufacturers produce both...

Easy enough to convert if you know what you are doing - a friend used to buy in France, import to UK and convert.

Only needed to purchase some bits - but that depends on the model. He did Minis at the time because the dash was central then so reduced the work.

An X type now would need a complete dash as well as quite a bit of stuff under the bonnet. Still possible if you have the tools. Do check things like pedal boxes. And consider the pipework that needs changing: brakes, clutch…

Comment: Thanks Mike. Are there countries which allow both Left hand drive and Right hand drive vehicles?

Comment: You can import them permanently, or just for 6 months: Switzerland. Some countries have post office delivery vehicles in the other "hand" to make life easier for post office workers delivering letters. Easily searched on that countries government website. But being left or right hand drive won't be a fail for a roadworthy test.

Comment: Also trucks can be purchased with the driver on the pavement side of the road so the driver can clean the road edge easily as well.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Can you throw light on military vehicles viz trucks, tanks, ambulances? How difficult or easy for Transition Left hand and Right hand drive military vehicles?

Comment: Landrover made military ambulances in left and right hand drive. The list is long, which means you can search for the specific vehicle you are concerned about.

Comment: Thanks Mike. No i mean the transition from left hand drive to right hand drive and vice versa would be more difficult for military vehicles as compared to Cars?

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar No, just the same - as long as you can get the parts. Check the manufacturer for the vehicle you are concerned with.

Comment: Most global brands produce cars in both - the UK, South Africa, and Australia are large enough markets. As one example, many Toyota models are available as-built in both left and right. Sometimes the conversion is done by an importer (I think Dodge Ram trucks in Australia are converted from left to right there).

Comment: Thanks for the information provided Mike & Jon. Is it possible using Robotics science to automate the Conversion process from Left hand vehicle to right hand vehicle using a Humanoid? I mean a Robot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're asking if it's difficult to transition from left hand to right hand drive vehicles. I can't speak for everyone but myself having experience in a right hand drive vehicle in NYC. It was so long ago and was a government vehicle whether or not I was required to take a road test to ensure I was able to discern differences between (normal) left hand driving to right  hand driving (unusual) in and around NYC. I don't recall much effort other than adjusting to seeing the left side of the vehicle relative to lane divider while using my minds eye to center the vehicle in a lane. Turning left would be another adjustment as right hand turns are easier to see the curb.

Comment: Thanks for the information provided. Apart from user experience in driving both left hand and right hand vehicles, received the information from Mike regarding the engineering efforts required to convert a left hand drive to right hand drive and vice versa.